# Is there any way to separate this short code into its own function? (webserver, trying to use client.print outside of main loop)

Tags: web-server

I have an arduino webserver that uses the following code:

```
client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
client.println(F("Content-Type: text/html"));
client.println();
client.println(F("<HTML><HEAD>"));
...
if (fan1Toggle == 0)
    client.print(F("Fan1<font color=\"red\">&#8226;</font><a href=\"/?fan1on\">On</a><br>"));
else
    client.print(F("Fan1<font color=\"green\">&#8226;</font><a href=\"/?fan1off\">Off</a><br>"));

if (fan2Toggle == 0)
    client.print(F("Fan2<font color=\"red\">&#8226;</font><a href=\"/?fan2on\">On</a><br>"));
else
    client.print(F("Fan2<font color=\"green\">&#8226;</font><a href=\"/?fan2off\">Off</a><br>"));
...
```

The page is pretty long, allowing the user to toggle over a dozen different switches. Some of the code checks to see the state of a certain switch, and then displays a green or red bullet ("&#8226", like •) on the page if the switch is on or off.

Since the code for the colored bullet is repeating, I wanted to make a function for it. Then I would just call (for example) "`displayBullet(fan1Toggle);`", and it would determine if fan1 was on or off, and display the correct color depending on the state.

I tried to create the following function:

```
void displayBullet(int toggle) {
if (toggle == 0)     //switch is off, so display red bullet
    client.print(F("<font color=\"red\">&#8226;</font>"));
else    //switch is on, so display green bullet
    client.print(F("<font color=\"green\">&#8226;</font>"));
}
```

But then I got an error saying that "'client' is not declared in this scope".

Is there any way to work around that error, so that I can get the displayBullet() function I want? Or is this something that can't be shortened like this, because the "client" function has to be inside the main loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass client to the function by reference, like this:

```C++
void displayBullet(EthernetClient & client, int toggle) 
  {
  if (toggle == 0)     //switch is off, so display red bullet
    client.print(F("<font color=\"red\">&#8226;</font>"));
  else    //switch is on, so display green bullet
    client.print(F("<font color=\"green\">&#8226;</font>"));
  }
```

Now it knows about `client`. Make sure you pass client when you call it:

```C++
displayBullet(client, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's very useful information to know, and I'm sure it'll help me in the future with other similar problems.